# PHP page not linking with updated css file

Tags: php, html, css

My CSS is linked in my head tag underneath the title tag like this:

```
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I was working with the styles yesterday and it was applying the styles well.

Today i am adding new styles and they are not working with the PHP file, it still has the css from yesterday when i check the page source even though i have changed the css file.

What has happened?

Comment: What's in your PHP file?

Comment: Try a hard reload (open your browser console, right click on the refresh button, and select "Hard Reload" or "Empty Cache and Hard Reload")

Comment: The PHP is used further down the page inside a div to show a gallery.

Comment: The hard reload worked!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hard reload is the correct fix here (CTRL+R in Chrome, similar in other browsers).

You can also fix the issue forever by appending your link to the css file with a query variable that changes, say, every day so that browsers will only cache the css file for a day.

```
<link href="css/main.css?date=<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>"> rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Adding the date as the query string is pretty genius. I've been using a config variable and manually managing my versions in the variable. Looks like I'm switching all of my applications to something of that nature.

Comment: Just noticed, the href wouldn't have worked as it was; now corrected.